# Heroku: Your account has reached its concurrent build limit

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku, currently using the free tier. Over the past 5 days I've been redeploying the app as I made changes. I went overzealous with the deploys and now my app is up to version 35 on heroku under the "activity" tab.

Now the error message in the title prevents me from deploying my app. Google search didn't return a thing. If I have reached the deployment limit how do I delete/free up my concurrent build space?

Comment: As of the last few days, I've had a few students who were getting this error message, and I got on their Heroku CLIs and verified there were no builds running on any of their apps. I'm 99% sure that in that case, it's just a Heroku system bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Heroku said "Engineers are investigating API availability. This may affect Dashboard, CLI commands, builds and other aspects of the platform." I think this is the reason.

Comment: still happening 2 years later, though

Comment: how about 3 years later

Comment: how about 3 years and 1 month later

Comment: How about 3 years, 2 months, 8 days later

Comment: we were not here for the Reason.

Comment: its happening on 2021

Comment: How about 3 years, 4 months, 19 Days

Comment: ahaha its been 4 years now

Comment: 4 years and 2 months

Comment: I guess that makes this 4 years and 3 months then

Comment: Reached 4 years and 4 months.

Comment: how about 4 years and 10 months

Comment: The real answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57910276/8659405

Comment: This answer shouldn't have been accepted, there are many other answers with the correct solutions.

Answer (score 109):

For my case, `heroku restart` worked.

Comment: It restarts all dynos when you do heroku restart. More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands

Answer (score 72):

We can cancel the current build. Or any ongoing build using below

`heroku builds:cancel`

You can check the list of builds using

`heroku builds`

Or you can cancel any build using build hash from the above result list.

In case builds command not working, you need to install it using

`heroku plugins:install heroku-builds`

Comment: I get `Warning: builds is not a heroku command.` with `heroku builds`. Wait, did not read until the end, now I installed the build plugin and it works..

Comment: heroku builds:cancel worked for me. 

Answer (score 70):

I had to try two of these answers back-to-back. Individually, they didn't work for me.

I needed to install `heroku-builds` with

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
```

Then cancel the ongoing build with

```
heroku builds:cancel
```

And finally did a `heroku restart`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. When you run `heroku builds:cancel` you may get the outout: `Can only cancel pending builds. Build c20a59ad-d093-4c04-bc70-85ec62f1da00 has status 'failed'`, don't panic, just run the `heroku restart` command next, and the build will start.

Answer (score 38):

Finally, I managed to resolve an issue with the help of the following 3 commands and it works:-

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
$ heroku builds:cancel
$ heroku restart
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this command from your project directory

```
heroku restart
```

Answer (score 5):

Now you have to verify your account, putting your credit card in Heroku Account.

"Unverified accounts can now run only one build at a time across all their apps. Verifying the account will automatically lift this limit."

see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1344

Answer (score 5):

I managed by mistake to cancele the build in the terminal by ctrl+c, but the build at heroku account was still running.

The correct way is:

If didn't installed earlier:

> heroku plugins:install heroku-builds

And then:

> heroku builds:cancel -a YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME

Answer (score 4):

This helped me "Restart all dynos"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### **Try to**:

- Try to check `https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1344` for important logs
- Try to reinstall your app(**%65** works)
- Try to create a new account(**%100** works)

Answer (score 0):

Pushing too many time a day to GitHub with auto redeploy will result to this error. The simplest solution is to delete your app on Heroku, create a new one and redeploy. Make sure your commit to GitHub has "Node" and "NPM" or "YARN" versions specified within the engines parameter in your package.json file.

Deleting and redeploying is the easiest bypass.

I don't think you need to verify your account using your credit/debit card. Especially on a personal account. Scope include minimum viable products (MVPs), personal projects or proof of concepts.

`

```
"name": "app name",

"version": "1.1.0",

"private": true or false,

 "engines": {

  "node": "16.14.0",

  "npm": "8.3.1"

},
```

`

Answer (score -1):

This also happens if you have your repo connected and set to auto-deploy.

I had this issue since I had just updated my repo, heroku had started a build already. So when you tell it to build there's already a build going on.

The solution is just to wait until the build finishes, or at least that solved it for me.

Answer (score -2):

If you are a little noob like me who just ran out of all deploys available. Just create a new app and the problem is then solved! Simple!