# heroku keep giving me this error when i try to push my app

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku, push, heroku-cli

I try to push my app to Heroku, but it keep giving me this error.

I did it before, but this time, I don't know the reason of the error.
I searched, but none of the solutions I have found helped me to solve this problem.
So anyone can tell me why this error happened ?

```
PS D:\my admin react project> git push heroku master
            Enumerating objects: 84, done.
            Counting objects: 100% (84/84), done.
            Delta compression using up to 4 threads
           **strong text** Compressing objects: 100% (77/77), done.
             Writing objects: 100% (84/84), 761.66 KiB | 2.21 MiB/s, done.
             Total 84 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0)
            remote: Compressing source files... done.
            remote: Building source:
            remote:
            remote: !       Your account has reached its concurrent builds limit
            remote:
             To https://git.heroku.com/driver-admin.git
             ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
            error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/driver-admi
        n.git'
```

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54662651/11330560

Comment: no it keep showing me the same error

Answer (score 1):

You just have to wait for a few minutes and it will start working.
Or you can just add your card details and verify your account.

Comment: this points to the right direction +1

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same Issue, if you go to the website and click "more" on top and then clicking "restart all dynos".

Answer (score 0):

Check and open the Windows Credentials Manager (which is, if you see "manager" when typing `git config credential.helper`, the cache for HTTPS credentials)

If you see the wrong username/password for `git.heroku.com`, that would explain the error message, since, as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57486256/6309), a wrong account, or even a correct but unverified one can now run only one build at a time across all their apps.

Comment: the problem solved i think there was a problem with heroku i just write 
( heroku ps:restart )
and push my project and it was okay
thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Also have a problem with deploying an app today. heroku has an incident: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1892

Comment: yes you are right i open it and write ( heroku ps:restart ) in my terminal and push my project and there was no problem , thanks so much 