# Is there a way to get Heroku app to deploy

Tags: github, heroku, deployment

I've been building an app hosted in Heroku, and until recently it's been working fine with automatic deploys from my Github repo, however recently it got stuck in the deploying phase and even when I deleted my app, started a new one, and hooked that up to my Github repo I got a "your build has reached its concurrent builds limit" error which makes me think there is a problem persisting somewhere, as when it got stuck deploying nothing appeared in any of the logs.

I've seen a bunch of commands on how to force stop a build however for various reasons I've been stuck working exclusively on the web and so can't have the Heroku CLI installed and those commands don't seem to work on the online console.

If there's any way I can get Heroku to cooperate that would be fantastic, as I'm pretty sure the error isn't with my code as I only added one small function that worked fine when tested elsewhere.

["your concurrent builds limit has been reached"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EYIE.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a side-effect of [their latest incident](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2454) (Issues with DNS resolution)

Try also and go to the website and click "more" on top and then clicking "restart all dynos" (as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66711777/6309)).

But mainly check if the issue persists in time.
And don't forget [Heroku free plan won't be there for much longer](https://techcrunch.com/2022/08/25/heroku-announces-plans-to-eliminate-free-plans-blaming-fraud-and-abuse).